# what is the daily limit of time based workflow email alert?

Tags: workflow, governorlimits, limits, email-alert, time-dependent-workflow

I have to send an reminder email after 2 week to user when the status is updated on record. I am thinking to use time based workflow. How many email will get send in 1 day? What is the limit of email alert per day?

Answer (score 2):

The daily allocation for emails sent through email alerts is 1,000 per standard Salesforce license per org—except for free Developer Edition and trial orgs, where the daily workflow email allocation is 15.

Please go through this [Link](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=workflow_limits_email.htm&type=5) for more details.